# How to make a right aligned td to top with the responsive view?

Tags: html, css, html-table

My table is aligned as main heading on right.

```html
<table style="height: 233px;" width="862">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3 ليالي و4 أيام</td>
      <td class="need-this-on-top">
        <h2><strong>المدة </strong></h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>تيكادي , آليبي , كوشين</td>
      <td class="need-this-on-top">
        <h2><strong>اماكن للزيارة</strong></h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Mobile View**

[image]

I need the bold text on top as a heading on the mobile view. How can I do this with css ?
I already tried the code below:

`display: table-header-group;`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox with `flex-direction: column` and change the **order**.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-stacked-reversed-mobile tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .td-stacked-reversed-mobile tr>td:nth-child(1) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .td-stacked-reversed-mobile tr>td:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Added class 'td-stacked-reversed-mobile' -->
<table class="td-stacked-reversed-mobile" style="height: 233px;" width="862">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3 ليالي و4 أيام</td>
      <td class="need-this-on-top">
        <h2><strong>المدة </strong></h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>تيكادي , آليبي , كوشين</td>
      <td class="need-this-on-top">
        <h2><strong>اماكن للزيارة</strong></h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hop this will help you

```
td {
 vertical-align:top
}
```